# Error fetching data from database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `reg_data` (
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `session` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` time default NULL,
  `temp_air` float NOT NULL,
  `rel_humid` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_5` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_20` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_30` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_60` float NOT NULL,
  `air_pressure` float NOT NULL,
  `anem_reading` float NOT NULL,
  `dry_temp` float NOT NULL,
  `wet_temp` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`date`,`session`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `reg_data3` (
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `rainfall` float default NULL,
  `evep` float default NULL,
  `max_temp` float default NULL,
  `min_temp` float default NULL,
  `sunshine_hrs` float default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to join these two tables using `date ='".$full."` passed from `$full=$month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;`.

My query is:

```
$sql ="(select A.date,A.rainfall,A.evep, A.max_temp, A.min_temp, A.sunshine_hrs,B.run , B.velocity From reg_data3 A  ,velocity B where A.date=B.date ORDER by A.date) WHERE date ='".$full."' ;
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: The fact that you're not using JOIN?

Comment: @Shomz: It's an implicit join. Not a good practice, but not invalid.

Comment: @Travesty3 I don't get the question then... `WHERE A.date=B.date AND A.date ='".$full."'`?

Comment: @Shomz: That's a potential solution. The problem that I see is that there is a select within the parens, and then outside of the parens, he's trying to add on an extra `WHERE` clause without a `SELECT` or `FROM`. So the solution would be to do as you just suggested, combine the two `WHERE` parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the parentheses in your query and put `date = '". $full . "'` after your first `WHERE` clause with an `AND`.

You also need to specify which table's `date` column to use for `date = '". $full . "'`, so change that to `A.date = '". $full . "'`

```
$sql ="select A.date,A.rainfall,A.evep, A.max_temp, A.min_temp, A.sunshine_hrs,B.run , B.velocity From reg_data3 A,velocity B where A.date=B.date AND A.date ='".$full."' ORDER by A.date;
```

I would also suggest formatting your query and using explicit joins instead of implicit ones:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        A.date,
        A.rainfall,
        A.evep,
        A.max_temp,
        A.min_temp,
        A.sunshine_hrs,
        B.run,
        B.velocity
    FROM
        reg_data3 A
        INNER JOIN velocity B
            ON A.date = B.date
    WHERE
        A.date = '". $full ."'
    ORDER BY
        A.date   /* this is pointless...they're all going to be the same date */
";
```

Comment: A.date = '". $full ."' it should be